# Redirect visitor based upon geolocation

Tags: redirection, location

On a Drupal website I want to redirect the visitor to a landing page based on the users location. I need this to be more specific than just the users country, but rather I need the province inside the country. When the user does not allow to be located, the user will go to the standard landing page...

Is there an (easy) way to achieve this? I am fairly new to the world of Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had pretty good results previously with [SmartIP](http://drupal.org/project/smart_ip), and now there is [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) integration which can react to which country the user is in.

So you should be able to set a Rule similar to the following psuedo-rule:

> **EVENT:**
>
> Page is going to be viewed
>
> **CONDITION:**
>
> - Page is: *Front page*
> - IP Address is in country: *whatever country you want*
>
> **ACTIONS:**
>
> Go to page: YOUR COUNTRY SPECIFIC LANDING PAGE

I know you said you were new to Drupal, so you can find some really useful [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) tutorials at [NodeOne: Learn the Rules Framework](http://nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework).

**EDIT**

I've just twigged you said you want it to the province level rather than country (sorry, that was glaringly obvious - my fault), so you might be looking at some custom code.

Last time I used it, I used SmartIP to get the latitude and longitude of the user, and then the [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location) API for the nitty gritty.

You should be able to combine this with [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) and [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) to redirect the user to the relevant page.